# Veutify form control: SELECT with CHIPS having issue with validation

Tags: vuetify.js

I am trying to use vuetify validation for a **select** that has a select all template and uses chips... Setting the :rules="[v => !!v || 'Item is required']" and required does not seem to work..  suggestions or links to read?
[CODE PEN EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/wlafrance/pen/KKpOaxM)

```
<v-select v-model="value" :items="items"
  attach
  chips
  label="Chips"
  multiple
  :rules="[v => !!v || 'Item is required']"
  required
></v-select>

items: ["foo", "bar", "fizz", "buzz"],
  value: ["foo", "bar", "fizz", "buzz"],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd define your rules in the data instead of on every `v-select`so you can easily adjust your rules in one place.
You had a typo too and your `methods` was called `methodds`. Remember to check for any errors in the dev console (F12) of your browser. The one `v-select` had a v-model called "select" but it was never defined in the data.

The following setup should work just fine.

```
<v-select v-model="select" :items="items" :rules="required" label="Item Validates just fine">
</v-select>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    valid: true,
    items: ['','foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz'],
    value: [],
    select: [],
    required: [(v) => v.length > 0 || "required"]
  }),
  methods:{
    validate(){
           this.$refs.form.validate();
    }
  }
})
```

Your previous rule with !!v does not work on arrays.
`!![]` evaluates to true
but `[].length > 0` evaluates to false <= this is what you want to check for required inputs.

Comment: So straight forward, thank you so much for the answer!  I also updated my code pen with your suggested fix.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already added values to the v-model, the validation rules will return true always. You need to initialize value as an empty array

```
data(){
  return {
    ...
    value: [],
    items: ["foo", "bar", "fizz", "buzz"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried that and added a CODE PEN with two selects.. To demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I understand that what you need is, the button should be active when both the v-select is not null, right?

Comment: You need to change the rule to :rules="[v => v.length > 0 || 'Item is required']" on both the v-select